# Is there a heuristic algorithm for groupBy + count?

Tags: algorithm, group-by, language-agnostic

I got a List of integers and I want to count the number of times each integer appears in the list.

For example: `[0,5,0,1,3,3,1,1,1]` gives `(0 -> 2), (1 -> 4), (3 -> 2), (5 -> 1)`. I only need the count, not the value (the goal is to have an histogram of the counts).

A common approach would be to group by value then count the cardinality of each set. In SQL: `SELECT count(*) FROM myTable GROUPBY theColumnContainingIntegers`.

Is there a faster way to do this? A heuristic or a probabilistic approach is fine since I am computing a large data set and sacrifying precision for speed is fine.

Something similar to HyperLogLog algorithm (used to count the number of distinct elements in a data set) would be great, but I did not find anything like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your set containing 9 elements `[0,5,0,1,3,3,1,1,1]` and make it big but with same frequencies of elements:

```
> bigarray = [0,5,0,1,3,3,1,1,1] * 200
 => [0, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, ...
```

Now bigarray size is 1800 so let's try to work with it.

Take a sample of 180 elements (random 180 elements from this set)

Now compute occurence for this random subset

```
{5=>19, 3=>45, 1=>76, 0=>40}
```

Normalized:

```
{5=>1.0, 3=>2.3684210526315788, 1=>4.0, 0=>2.1052631578947367}
```

Of course for different random subset results will be different:

```
{5=>21, 3=>38, 1=>86, 0=>35}
```

Normalized

```
{5=>1.0, 3=>1.8095238095238095, 1=>4.095238095238095, 0=>1.6666666666666667}
```

Of course there are some errors there - this is inevitable and you will need to state what will be acceptable error

Now make same test for bigarray (size 1000) with 50% of 0's and 50% of 1's

```
 > bigarray = [0,1] * 500
 => [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,  ...
```

With sample of 100 elements:

```
{0=>50, 1=>50}
```

Normalized

```
{0=>1.0, 1=>1.0}
```

Second sample:

```
{0=>49, 1=>51}
```

Normalized

```
{0=>1.0, 1=>1.0408163265306123}
```

It seems that we can easily reduce our subset and here [Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)) comes.

Especially [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) - this may be very useful if in your case data is populated 'live' or set is too large to process all values at once.

**edit**

Concerning comment:
Of course if you have large set and some element appears there very rare then you may have lost it and occurence will equal 0.

Then you may use kind of smoothing function (check [additive smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing)). Just assume that each possible element 1 more time than it really appeared.

For example let's say we have set:

```
1000 elements 1
100 elements 2
10 elements 3
1 elements 4
```

Let's say our subset contains {1=>100,2=>10,3=>1, 4=>0}

Smoothing param = 0.05 so we add 0.05 to each occurence

{1=>100.05,2=>10.05,3=>1.05, 4=>0.05}

Of course this is assuming that you know what values are even possible to be present in the set.

Comment: I already tried sampling but this only works when every distinct element appears a sufficient amount of times in the array. As you sample an array of `n` element by only computing on `n*p` elements (where `p` is a proportion between 0 and 1), you get a probability of approximately `(1-p)**k` not to detect an element that appears `k` times (if `n>>k`).

Comment: If you try have an array of at least millions of elements (which is the case if you need sampling), you won't detect a part of these elements. This can be problematic since you lose then a non negligible part of your elements diversity.

Comment: I tried to couple sampling to estimate recurrent elements, and hyperLogLog to estimate the distinct elements cardinality (which gave me a rought estimate of how many distinct elements I did not detect). The problem is that an undetected element can appear 1 time or 100 times or even more if you are unlucky.

Comment: Thus sampling is only accurate enough unless it is close to 100%, which is kind of useless then.

Comment: But don't get me wrong, if you only have elements that appear a lot in you array, your answer is totally relevant and accurate.

Comment: Updated my answer, consider using smoothing

Comment: I was sceptical about this, but additive smoothing is actually pretty accurate!